# Redirect to first page if user refresh the browser in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a URL for product page like `http://localhost:3000/product?page=1` and at the bottom of the page there is a button `Load More`. If we click that button, it will change the URL `http://localhost:3000/product?page=2` (without reloading the page) and show the products for the page.
I want that if user **refresh** the browser and `page>1` then user should redirect to `page=1`. i.e; We don't allow page refresh if `page > 1`
Basically, question is about to detect page reload.

I tried :

```
if (window.performance) {
  if (PerformanceNavigationTiming.type == 1) {
    alert( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    alert( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```

But this did not work for me.

Comment: So, you want to prevent reload? Or do you want to have a certain behavior on reload? If it is the latter, then you could just have add a check of the URL each time the page get loaded and depending on the URL redirect or not.

Comment: I am saying that "if `page>1` in url and user refresh the browser or manually entered `http://localhost:3000/product?page=2`, then user should redirect to page=1".

Comment: At the bottom of the page there is a button `Load More`. If we click that button, it will change the URL for the next page `http://localhost:3000/product?page=2` (without reloading the page)

Comment: Then add a check of the URL in the beginning of the JS file, so that each time the page is loaded, you check, if page > 1 and if it is redirect to page=1.

Comment: Are you using React Router Dom? If so which version?

Comment: @yousoumar "react-router-dom": "~5.1.0"

Comment: @Geshode If I do check `if page > 1 and if it is redirect to page=1` then user will not be able to reach to `page 2`. _(Please read my question again)_. User is allowed to the next page through `Load More` button. But if user manually changed URL then this is not allowed.

Comment: Well, you said, that through the load more button you go to the next page without reloading the page, so the code in the beginning of the JS file wouldn't be executed again, because there is no reload.

Comment: @Geshode Have you ever worked on ReactJS ?

Comment: Are you updating the value of ‘page’ query parameter in your code? If so you can just skip doing that, and instead keep the (incremented) page number in a state variable. That way the url in browser always points to the first page, and refresh will automatically take your there.

Comment: Yes, if we press "Load More" button, `page` query in the URL changes to the next page (like from page=1 to page=2) and then component re-renders, another API calls for `page 2` and we show products for that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to do is something when the page component mounts for the first time, for example setting the page number back to 1.
So on the page component inside `useEffect(()=>{ //do whatever you want,like setting the page no to 1 },[])` - which will be called once every time when the page mounts.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, I am coding continuously from last 10 hours and my mind is not able to solve simple problems now ....haha